# Simple widget buttons - Lua - Corona SDK

Tags: android, lua, widget, coronasdk

So I'm working on my first project in Corona SDK and I'm pretty new to it. I was just wondering how to make widget based button thats function is to display and hide an image?

in simple way;

-there's a button

-when you press it, some image appears on screen

-you press it once more - that image disappears

Any easy code ideas? - I'm new

Thanks!

Comment: StackOverflow is not for recommendations, and is for Troubleshooting and Programming help, however, if you're new to Lua, I recommend checking out [Programming in Lua](https://www.lua.org/pil/1.html) And for Corona, [This](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-lua-and-the-corona-sdk--mobile-21457) is a helpful tutorial.

Comment: I know that. What i've posted below is my problem, cause I couldn't get exact answer on Corona forums and have been sitting in lua not for so short - but i still can't figure out how to make that button ( probably beacuse of my english problems :/ ) - so I'm in trouble and I want to get qucik readable reply that'd allow me to continue working on my app- that's why I'm writing in here.

Comment: Start from [Chapter 1 — Creating an App](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/programming/01/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should define a flag to show/hide the image. Wehnever you tap the button the flag become **true** and the image become shown. And Whenever you tap it once more the flag become **false** and the image become hide.

This algorithm is like the following code in Corona SDK:

```
-- define flag outside click event --
local flag = false

-- in click event --
if flag == false then
  -- show image in here --
else
  -- hide image in here  --
end
```

Of course, There are other ways to do this work.